# Find a string within an Excel file and get the row index

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to access an Excel file through Word and to search for a string.

I am trying to get the whole row (for example: I am looking for the string "Hello world" in cell A7, then trying to get all the dates in row 7) then to place that info into my Word file at a precise location.

Here is an example of the Excel file:

```
No       site           trig           type 
1        steve          stv            7
2        Nancy          nco            3
```

etc..

```
Public Function test(ByVal strTitle As String, ByVal strTrigram As String) As String
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlBook As Object
    Dim strName As String
    Dim col As Column

    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err Then
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(ActiveDocument.Path & "/FichierTrigrammes.xlsx")
    xlApp.Visible = False  'does not open the file, read only => faster to get the info

    With xlBook.Sheets(1).Cells
        Set rfind = .Find(What:=strTitle) ' on cherche si il y a ue colonne avec le nom
        If rfind Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Pas de colonne avec ce titre"
            Exit Function
        End If
        MsgBox rfind.Column
        'Debug.Print "L'index de la colonnne" & titleCol &; " est "; rfind.Column
    End With

    Dim ra As Range

    Set ra = Cells.Find(What:="SLD", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
      :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
      False, SearchFormat:=False) 'there is a pb with find

    If ra Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Not found"
        Else
        MsgBox ra.Address
    End If         

    strName = "okay"
    'strName = xlBook.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(what:=strTrig)
    xlBook.Close False ' no save
    Set src = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlBook = Nothing
    test = strName

End Function
```

I am trying to search if the header in the Excel file is what I need, then to locate the string (that should be here) and get the row index to get the whole row but an error pops up saying there is problem at the method find.

Answer (score 2):

```
Set ra = Cells.Find(What:="SLD", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False) 'there is a pb with find
```

`Cells` is part of your Excel application object, not part of your Word vba environment, so you need to qualify it as you did above

```
Dim ra As Object 'not Range

Set ra = xlBook.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="SLD", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It improved my code.
Even so, i got another error:
Dim ra As Range

    Set ra = xlBook.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="SLD", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False) 'there is a pb with find

    If ra Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Not found"
        Else
        MsgBox ra.Address  'it says method or data member not found
    End If


and since i cant acces the addres i cannot copy the row

Comment: `Dim ra As Object` not `Dim ra As Range` - if you use `Range` in Word's VBA environment it will assume you mean `Word.Range` not `Excel.Range`  The Word `Range` object doesn't have an `Address` property

Comment: Thanks it worked better.
Here it is:

Dim ra as Object
Set ra =  xlBook.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="SLD") 'works without the other arguments
msgbox ra.address ' just to see that it works

Comment: The only thing I'd caution about not using the other arguments to `Find()` is that those default to the *last-used* settings. i.e. if you previously searched for something using `xlWhole` then that's what your VBA will use unless you specify otherwise by providing that argument.